# Trying to make the sub menu toggle with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello Everyone I've been doing quite alot of research on this.

Can't Find the solution.

I'm trying to keep the menu sub nav active on mouse out.

Basically the exact same as the bootstrap menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/pentester/DDpH6/

```
        <div id="nav_wrap">
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">parent</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="last_item"><a class="last_item" href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">parent</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">child</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="last_item" href="#">child/a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">parent</a>
                        </li>
                        <li style="border-right:1px solid #171717"><a a href="#">parent</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
            </div>


        #nav_wrap {
            background: #000;
            height: 60px
        }

        #nav {
            float: right;
        }
        #nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        #nav li a {
            font-size: 0.9em;
            color: #FFF;
            display: block;
            padding: 0 26px;
            text-decoration: none;

            font-family: opensans;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        #nav li a:hover {
            background: #1B1A1A;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
        }
        #nav ul li {
            float: left;
            position: relative;
        }
        #nav ul li a {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 0 26px;
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #FFF;
            line-height: 60px;
        }
        #nav ul li ul {
            display: none;
        }
        #nav ul li:hover ul {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
        }
        #nav ul li:hover ul li a {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #232323;
            border-left: medium none;
            color: #FFFFFF;
            display: block;
            font-family: opensans;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            line-height: 35px;
            text-align: left;
            width: 190px;
            padding: 0 15px;
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            -o-transition: all 0.2s ease;
            transition: all 0.2s ease;
            text-transform:capitalize;
        }
        #nav ul li:hover ul li a:hover {
            background: #069;
            color: #fff;
        }
        #nav ul li ul li {
            border-top:1px solid #2A2A2A
        }
        .last_item {
            border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
        }
        .home {
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }


          $("#nav ul li ul li").hide();

          $("#nav ul li").click(function(){
            $("#nav ul li ul li").toggle();



          }); 

          $("#nav").mouseout(function(){
            $("#nav ul li ul li").show();



          });
```

I feel like the problem is really small. I'm just not getting it.

Comment: The boostrap nav only shows on click, it's what you want? Right now your code it shows on hover, which causes some different behavior. Let me know if you want to toggle onclick only.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a CSS `:hover` to reveal the submenus, use a jQuery `click` event:

```
$("#nav > ul > li").on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Clicking a list item toggles the `.active` class, which controls the visibility of the submenu:

```
#nav > ul > li > ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav > ul > li.active > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is a modified version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2mRwb/3/

Comment: Thanks for this. I used the over as a no script fallback. Now if the user click's away from the nav I want the nav to collapse, so there is one sub menu active at any time. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed your jquery and also your css. The stule needs some improvement, but the behavior is what you want.

```
 $("#nav ul li ul li").hide();

  $("#nav ul li").click(function(){
    $(this).find('ul').toggle()
  }); 

  $("#nav").mouseout(function(){
    $("#nav ul li ul li").show();

  });
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDpH6/1/)